# How to sort and filter using metadata in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using metadata on blobs in a Google Cloud Storage bucket to store important information regarding a specific blob. I would like to use the `Sort and filter` functionality that is available from the Cloud Storage UI a bit more extensively. The available filter properties seem to be:

- Name contains
- Name prefix
- Size (bytes)
- Type
- Created on
- Created before
- Created after
- Storage class
- Last modified on
- Last modified before
- Last modified after
- Public access
- Version history
- Encryption
- Retention expires on
- Retention expires before
- Retention expires after
- Holds

But no filter property for metadata is available. However, some functionality to filter on metadata seems to be present. For example. If there are two files present, one with the metadata key-value pair `special_key: true` and the other one no metadata tag and I filter (in the UI) with `Sort and filter`, `special_key` then the only file that remains is the one with the tag.

However, I cannot filter more specifically on the label, for example `special_key = true` to only show the blobs with a certain value of a metadata key. Is there a way to do this? A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47554880/can-i-search-google-cloud-storage-bucket-using-metadata-values), but the best answer solves this by using the SDK and not the UI itself, which is the preferred solution.

Comment: What sort of activity you would like to perform after sort/filter using metadata ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console#_filtering) :

> In the Cloud Console list of objects for a bucket, you can filter the
> objects you see by specifying a prefix in the Filter by object or
> folder name prefix... text box, located above the list of objects.
> This filter displays objects beginning with the specified prefix. The
> prefix only filters objects in your current bucket view: it does not
> select objects contained in folders.

For your case, you can do  this [answer_1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38815564/15774176) and [answer_2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55352765/15774176) :

> You would need to list all the objects and then filter at the client
> side. Another option, if it's possible to rename your objects, would
> be to construct your object names such that the metadata values on
> which you want to filter are built into the beginning of the object
> names. You could then use a prefix filter on the listing request.

There is one Public issue tracker created on the similar issue , you can take a [look](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/119209458).

For more information, you can refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-python).

Comment: @Ward Van Driessche Posted an answer, Is it helpful?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DivyaniYadav. Unfortunately, adapting the file names to include metadata in the prefix is not doable.

Is there something on the roadmap to incorporate this functionality in GCS or not?

Answer (score -1):

how about: GCS --> Cloud Functions --> some database; use the db index for filtering/searching

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).